# NestJS com TypeOrm para MySQL - NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, crud, typeorm

Estou começando na área então desculpe se for algo bobo.

Comecei a desenvolver um server usando NestJS com TypeOrm para conectar em um banco MySQL mas estou pegando o seguinte erro: 'No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?'

Sem utilizar o TypeOrm consigo rodar o server.

"User" é minha entidade.

**app.module**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'mysql',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            username: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'meuserver',
            entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
            synchronize: true,
            logging: true
        }),
        UserModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private connection: Connection,
    ) { }
}
```

**user.module**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
            User,
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService,
    ],
    controllers: [
        UserController,
    ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**user.entity**

```
@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column()
    name?: string;
    @Column({ name: 'last_name' })
    lastName?: string;

    @Column({ default: false })
    active?: boolean;
}
```

Poderiam me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou quando passei as configurações para um arquivo 'ormconfig.json'
Segue abaixo:

**app.module**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        UserModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private connection: Connection,
    ) { }
}
```

**ormconfig.json**

```js
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "meuserver",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "autoLoadEntities": true,
    "entities": ["./src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}", "./dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seja bem-vindo à nossa comunidade, LittleFish!

O decorador **@Column** deve receber um objeto do tipo **ColumnOptions** [(Decorators Reference)](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#column).

Portanto, no atributo 'lastName', o decorador deve ficar dessa forma:

```
@Column({ name: 'last_name' })
lastName?: string;
```

Caso contrário, será interpretado como um 'tipo de dado', e não como 'nome de coluna'. ;)

Comment: Eu ajustei isso, mas o erro persiste

Comment: @LittleFish apague a pasta 'dist' e execute tudo novamente.

Comment: O problema estava nas minhas configs do TypeOrmModule. O caminho das entities estava errado. Agora estou pegando outro erro mas é outro tópico. Obrigado pela ajuda